# How to set Lucene with following error on Mac?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lucene, classpath

I am having trouble on setting up classpath on Mac. The following is the code I have attempted,

**First I exported the jars using terminal**

```
abc-MacBook-Pro:~ abc$ export   

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/abc/Desktop/IR/luceneJar/demo/lucene-demo-4.0.0.jar: export 

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/abc/Desktop/IR/luceneJar/core/lucene-core-4.0.0.jar: export 

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/abc/Desktop/IR/luceneJar/queryparser/lucene-queryparser-4.0.0.jar: export 

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Users/abc/Desktop/IR/luceneJar/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.0.jar
```

**Then when I echoed the classpath, following is the result**

```
abc-MacBook-Pro:~ abc$ echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/abc/Desktop/IR/lucene-4.0.0 2/core/lucene-core 4.0.0.jar:
/Users/abc/Desktop/IR/lucene-4.0.0 2/demo/lucene-demo-4.0.0.jar:
/Users/abc/Desktop/IR/luceneJar/analysis/common/lucene-analyzers-common-4.0.0.jar
```

**The error I am having is following when I tried to function the index file**

```
abc-MacBook-Pro:~ abc$ java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -docs

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/demo/IndexFiles
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Please let me know about the above error, thank you in advance. I am quite new with Lucene Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is common Java classpath problem, nothing related to lucene (or mac) here.

Try this

```
1) Create lib folder and move all your lucene jars to lib
    - lets say your project has two folders now lib and src, lib has all jars and src has yourJavaFile.java 

2) Run below commands for compilation and execution from your src
   - javac -cp ".:../lib/*" yourJavaFile.java
   - java -cp ".:../lib/*" yourJavaFile
```